# Как сделать сначала симуляцию жидкости и ее замерзание в blender?

Tags: 3d, blender, design

Для моей работы необходимо чтобы жидкость налилась в ёмкость(использую симуляцию), а в последствии на определенном промежутке времени кристаллизовалась(превратилась в лёд).